# Evitar que JDateChooser recalcule la fecha

Tags: java

La clase JDateChooser cuando recibe una fecha erronea la trata de corregir, como puedo evitar dicho comportamiento?

```
JDateChooser jDateChooserFecha=new JDateChooser();    
SimpleDateFormat formatoFecha = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
jDateChooserFecha.setDate(formatoFecha.parse("30/02/2016"));
```

Si ejecuto el código anterior el valor que se almacena en jDateChooserFecha es "02/03/2016"

Comment: ¿Tiene que exista un objeto `Date`  con una fecha errónea? De hecho, dado que la fecha se guarda en los `Date` como un número de milisegundos ¿puede existir un ojbeto `Date` con una fecha errónea? Quizás lo que detectas pase **antes** de asignar el valor a `JDateChooser`. Y por cierto ¿para qué quieres introducir una fecha errónea?

Comment: JDateChooser es de la librería JCalendar no?

Answer (score 0):

`JDateChooser` detecta al año `2016` como no bisiesto , **El mes de febrero solo tiene 28 días**, al asignar con día `30` , el resultado final sería el 02 de marzo **(02/03)** , creo que el resultado es correcto.

Una opción sería usar la clase [Calendar](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) para que también tenga en cuenta los años bisiestos.

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.set(2016, Calendar.FEBRUARY, 28);
JDateChooser jDateChooserFecha=new JDateChooser(c.getTime());
```